# Ubuntu doesn't see some Android devices

Tags: android

- I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 that I have no problem connecting to my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop.
- I have another android device (Prestigio Multipad 7.0 plus) that Ubuntu doesn't see at all, but Windows 7 does.

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I just crawling on the similar topic. Please check it out.

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53243/how-do-i-mount-my-samsung-galaxy-s4-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702

However, I only needed to do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libmtp-common mtp-tools libmtp-dev libmtp-runtime libmtp9
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

edit `/etc/fuse.conf` and remove the `#` before `user_allow_other`, then connect.

The article goes on a bit further, but I stopped because I couldn't recognize my device in the `lsusb` command. But it seems to work :)